# How to use left join with order by?

Tags: mysql

I have USER table(master table) and ONLINE table(refrence table with one to one relationship with USER) like below:
I used left join on tables
[image]

I am applying order by on "is_logged" field of ONLINE Table.(ASC) 
And I got the records in assending order, but all records are coming first which are not present in ONLINE table.
I want to all record of user table order but those records should be come last which are not present in online table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out.

```
SELECT  o.*
FROM     users u
             LEFT JOIN online 
                 o ON u.id = o.user_id
ORDER BY COALESCE(is_logged, -1) DESC, user_id ASC
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd16e/9)

Answer (score 1):

Give it a value bigger than 0 and 1 when null.

```
SELECT
  u.*, IFNULL(o.is_logged, 99) as is_logged
FROM
  user u
LEFT JOIN online o ON u.id = o.user_id
ORDER BY is_logged ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Xdazz, it was the usefull for me.